Event system: What is the problem described in this example?
Recently I‘ve been learning about event systems. As done does, I also did a Google search on the topic and found the following example in a blog:
export class Signal<S, T> {
    private handlers: Array<(source: S, data: T) => void> = [];

    public on(handler: (source: S, data: T) => void): void {
        this.handlers.push(handler);
    }

    public off(handler: (source: S, data: T) => void): void {
        this.handlers = this.handlers.filter(h => h !== handler);
    }

    public trigger(source: S, data: T): void {
        // Duplicate the array to avoid side effects during iteration.
        this.handlers.slice(0).forEach(h => h(source, data));
    }
}


class Dog {
    private readonly onBark = new Signal<Dog, string>();

    constructor(readonly name: string) {}

    public get BarkEvent(): Signal<Dog, string> {
        return this.onBark;
    }

    public sayWoof() {
        this.onBark.trigger(this, "WOOF!");
    }
}

class EvilDogListener {
    constructor(dog: Dog) {
        let dogBarkHandler = (s: Dog, bark: string) => {
            console.log(`Listener: Dog "${dog.name}" barked: ${bark}`);
        }
        dog.BarkEvent.on(dogBarkHandler);

        // NOW I CAN MAKE THE DOG BARK!
        dog.BarkEvent.trigger(dog, "FAKE WOOF!")
    }
}

Because EvilDogListener has access to Dog, it also has access to onBark, meaning it is also able to trigger events with it.
According to the blog, this is a problem:

Ops. Now the listener can make the dog bark! This is a clear violation of what an event subscriber can do.

Unfortunately for me as a learner this is not so clear.

Why is this behaviour a problem?
What is the underlying pattern or assumption I need to know to see why it is a problem?


Producers generate events to signal to subscribers that an interesting thing has happened (somebody bought an item, etc). And then the event subscribers do something with that event (like charge the credit card). So, event subscribers are not supposed to trigger the event.
